# Workaround for compile-time constant requirement in ASP.NET Core DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, data-annotations

I have various config values defined in the database or appsettings. But those cannot be used in `DataAnnotation` attributes (which require compile-time constants), so everything is duplicated in a `Constants` class too.

For example:

```cs
[StringLength(Constants.NAME_MAX_LENGTH, ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

One can use **localisation** to get the error message at runtime (from appsettings, database, etc.) and thus skirt the compile-time constant limitation, but as far as I can tell one cannot use the same approach for the min/max properties too (is that correct?)

Is there some roundabout way I can do something similar for the `MinimumLength` and `MaximumLength` properties, so that they can be read dynamically at runtime?

Comment: This is what I found just from a brief search. Hope it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593228/how-can-i-use-a-variable-or-class-property-in-a-dataannotation

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0